# How can I access objects from my Activity in a Worker? (to periodically change a notification)

Tags: android, androidx, worker, android-workmanager

I would like to periodically change a notification's text in a Worker. (androidx.work.WorkManager)

My MainActivity looks like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

    ...

    private void startNotification() {

        ...

        notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), warnotifier_notification_channel)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                            .setContentText(notificationText)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                            .setOngoing(true);

        notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

        notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());

        PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class, PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .addTag(workTag)
                    .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
    }

   ...

}
```

and my Worker looks like this

```
public class NotificationWorker extends Worker {
    public NotificationWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        String notificationText = "Time: " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(notificationText);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, Android does not allow me to put the Worker as a nested class in my MainActivity, and therefore I can't access the NotificationManagerCompat and NotificationCompat.Builder instances like above.

I know I can pass simple data with `periodicWorkRequest.setInputData(inputData)` to the Worker but I don't think that helps ...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, Android does not allow me to put the Worker as a nested
> class in my MainActivity, and therefore I can't access the
> NotificationManagerCompat and NotificationCompat.Builder instances
> like above.

Why you need to add your `NotificationWorker` class within the `MainActivity`?

As you mentioned you just want to access `NotificationManagerCompat` and `NotificationCompat.Builder` from the `Worker` class and there is no restriction to that, so to build your notification you already have a context passed to `Worker` class constructor, and also you can still call `getApplicationContext()` from the `Worker` class.
I have tested that without any problem.

Hope that helps. I am welcome if you have any queries.

> **Update**
>
> In my Worker class I wanted to access the `notificationManagerCompat`
> and `notificationBuilder` instances I created in `MainActivity`.

You don't have to create `notificationManagerCompat` & `notificationBuilder` instances in `MainActivity`, you can normally create them in `NotificationWorker`

Here is a demo from your code

```
public class NotificationWorker extends Worker {
    private final NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat;
    private final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

    public NotificationWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                (context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), warnotifier_notification_channel)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                        .setContentText(notificationText)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                        .setOngoing(true);

        notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        String notificationText = "Time: " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(notificationText);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

And you can get `notificationTitle`, `notificationText` from res/string using R.string.XX, and `notification_icon` from res/drawable using R.drawable.XX.

With this you can use `NotificationManagerCompat` and `NotificationCompat.Builder` from your Worker, all you need just a context, no need to activity.

hope this answers your question.

Comment: But how does the context help me to access `notificationManagerCompat` and `notificationBuilder`? I can't cast it to MainActivity since it's the Application context.

Comment: @Colin What type of objects you want to access on the MainActivity?

Comment: In my Worker class I wanted to access the `notificationManagerCompat` and `notificationBuilder` instances I created in MainActivity. I'm using androidbash's solution now unless you have a better idea.

Comment: Hi @Colin you can create those instances in your custom `Worker` instead of `MainActivity`; you can normally call `getApplicationContext()` in Worker class or use `context` parameter in its constructor .. please check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a notification with same ID (**So maintain a constant ID for your notification**) and notify. It updates the existing one automatically

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        Create a notification object with same ID as previous one and use notify to update the existing one.
    }
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like using new `NotificationCompat.Builder` and `NotificationManagerCompat` instances in the Worker but the same ID for the notification works.

Why do you get the `NotificationManager`? I don't need it to update my notification.

And does this way have any disadvantages? How I understand it am I now not just replacing the notification's text but the whole notification.

Comment: You can use this NotificationManagerCompat instead of NotificationManager